# Conversion float into time in JS

Tags: javascript, python, time, format, odoo

I'm using Odoo ERP for web development and I have an issue with the time format.
When I insert a time into the Odoo interface it's converted internally into another format, like is showed in the next images:
(1) User interface
(2) Database

[image: Odoo interface]
[image: BD]

The conversion is made for the **minutes** and it uses the next formula.

20 -> 0,3333

30 -> 0,5

60 -> 1

I need a function like timedelta in python for JavaScript:

```
minutes = //get the data
str(timedelta(hours=minutes)
```

Anyone has any idea about it?
Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply convert a time into float by dividing the number of minutes by 60 and summing the result to the number of hours.

*In JavaScript:*

```js
date = new Date(); // create new date
date.setHours(3, 24, 0); // set time to 03:24:00
console.log(date); // Fri Feb 21 2020 03:24:00 GMT+0100
dateFloat = date.getHours() + date.getMinutes() / 60; // convert 03:24:00 to floating-point number
console.log(dateFloat); // 3.4
```

*In Python:*

```py
from datetime import time

time = time(3, 24) # set time to 03:24
print(time) # 3:24:00
timeFloat = time.hour + time.minute / 60.0; # convert 03:24:00 to floating-point number
print(timeFloat) # 3.4
```